# error in t(dat1) and pairwise not found errors in R

Tags: r, genetics, pairwise

Can someone tell me why the **Error in t(dat1) : object 'dat1' not found** is appearing, and why **Error in is.element("pairwise", names(x)) : object 'pwStats' not found** is too?

I'm new to R, and I am trying to visualize the Djost graph shown [here](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/2041-210X.12067#mee312067-fig-0002):

```
pwStats <-fastDivPart(infile = microsatellitecoyreadyforR, 

                       outfile = "Coyote_resultspwstats",

                       gp = 2, bs_locus = TRUE,

                       bs_pairwise = TRUE, boots = 3)
Error in t(dat1) : object 'dat1' not found

 #visualize pwStats 

 diffPlot(x=pwStats,outfile = "Coyote_resultspwstats", interactive=TRUE)
Error in is.element("pairwise", names(x)) : object 'pwStats' not found
```

Comment: `infile` needs to be the name of a genepop file (in quotations)

Comment: @Esther , sorry, but I am still very new to R, and I am not sure how to make the infile a genepop file. I spent the past four hours trying to understand GenAlEx on excel, attempting to convert things into a genepop file, and inputting the information into the function. I've been able to import things, but what do I do once I have the imported data set? How do I tell R to run it?

Comment: Don't import the file, just add the path to the file in quotes.